# Examples of REST over non-HTTP protocols

Tags: rest, protocols, network-protocols

How well does REST work on other protocols besides HTTP?
Are there any good examples for protocols who use REST or might use REST?

Comment: Anything particular you had in mind? Do you want to use something leaner then http?

Comment: I am conducting a presentation about REST. I would like to demonstrate that it is not coupled with HTTP.

Comment: @the_ajp: Not really except the one Darrel Miller mentioned.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think you are going to find many, but [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-core-coap/) is one for embedded systems.

Comment: Because HTTP is so well suited to REST, there are very few occasions where another protocol would be a better choice.