# What protocols (other than HTTP) are used in REST APIs?

Tags: api, rest, http

I'm working on a REST API and asked myself out of curiosity which protocols are used (other than HTTP) that conform to the architectural principles required by REST.

Maybe you know of an example out there where a REST API is implemented with another protocol?

Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: well, you can use https :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Examples of REST over non-HTTP protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510880/examples-of-rest-over-non-http-protocols)

Comment: @Berto99 The application layer in https is still http so that doesn't really help :D

Comment: @Martheen Thanks that's at least one example of another protocol in use. But maybe there's another protocol out there regarding the post you linked is from 2010

Comment: You can construct a custom rest protocol however you want. For example include all the necessary data (uri, method and content) as JSON frames over raw TCP. There's no real obstacle here. In fact it is likely that most protocols can handle rest, if they can handle strings of arbitrary length. So the question isn't really well stated.

Comment: @freakish I hoped for some examples that are already in use. As I said I'm using HTTP myself but I wondered if there are other implementations out there

Comment: @thisidid Now this is a different question. You won't find any useful examples in the wild. Very unlikely.